# Упростить JS-условия a == 1 && b == 2 || a == 2 && b == 1

Tags: javascript

Есть ряд условий вида

```
if(a == 1 && b == 2 || a == 2 && b == 1) {
    c = 4;
}
if(a == 1 && b == 3 || a == 3 && b == 1) {
    c = 7;
}
```

Поскольку условия "симетричны", то их можно упростить если прописать в виде хеша:

```
{"1-2":4, "1-3":7, ...}
```

Но как пользоваться таким хешем вместо условий если на входе есть a и b?

Приведите хотя бы один простой пример чтобы понять суть

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно точно определить большее и меньшее значение, потом сформировать ключ и обратиться с ключом к хешу

```js
var hash = {"1-2": 4, "1-3": 7};
if (b < a) {
  var tmp = a;
  a = b;
  b = tmp;
}
var key = a + "-" + b;
c = hash[key]
```